# Google Charts Embed API is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics-api

I'm using Embed API to include GA charts on my site from ServiceAccount.
The site is a Single Page application with AngularJS.
I've created several directives for every chart type and a controller, name it `GAController`, shared between them. In this controller i use `gapi.analytics.ready(..)` to wait until analytics object is fully loaded.

The problem is that when `GAController` is called for first time after page refresh, then `gapi.analytics.ready(..)` is called with callback function and then authentication and other logic executes.
Hovewer, if i go to this page for the **second time** f.e. from other page via `ui-router`, then callback is added to `ready` but not executed. At all.

at the template page bottom, there's `gapi script`:

```
  (function(w,d,s,g,js,fjs){
g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(cb){this.q.push(cb)}};
js=d.createElement(s);fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics')};}
(window,document,'script'));
```

my code is the following:

```
gapi.analytics.ready(function () {
  // this is not called the second time
  if (!gapi.analytics.auth.isAuthorized()) {
    gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
      serverAuth: $scope.$parent.getAccessToken()
    });
  }
  // do some other logic
});
```

but all the times `gapi.analytics` object is in the same state `{ q: [], ready: function()...}`.

Can somebody help me to understand what's going on.
Thanks for any help

Comment: I have same problems , anyone help us

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.
You can try this, alternate the "gapi script"

```
                    (function (w, d, s, g, js, fs) {
                    if ($('#googleCache').length > 0) return;
                    g = w.gapi || (w.gapi = {}); g.analytics = { q: [], ready: function (f) { this.q.push(f); } };
                    js = d.createElement(s); fs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                    js.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
                    js.id = "googleCache";
                    fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fs); js.onload = function () { g.load('analytics'); };
                }(window, document, 'script'));
```